# Prove ${b_n} = \sup \{ {a_k}:k \geqslant n\} $for $n \geqslant 1$. Prove that $({b_n})$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

(a) Let $\left( {{a_n}} \right)_{n = 1}^\infty $ be bounded sequence. Define s sequence .${b_n} = \sup \{ {a_k}:k \geqslant n\} $for $n \geqslant 1$. Prove that $({b_n})$ converges. 
Proof 
    Let  set ${A_k}$ Where 
        $${A_k} = \{ {a_k},{a_{k + 1}},{a_{k + 2}},...\} $$ for $k \in \{ 1,2,3,...\} $ 
        $$bn = \sup \{ {a_k},{a_{k + 1}},{a_{k + 2}},...\} $$ 
        $${A_1} = \{ {a_1},{a_2},{a_3},...\} $$ $${b_1} = \sup \{ {a_1},{a_2},{a_3},...\} $$
        $${A_2} = \{ {a_2},{a_3},{a_4},...\} $$ $${b_2} = \sup \{ {a_2},{a_3},{a_4},...\} $$
$${A_3} = \{ {a_3},{a_4},{a_5},...\} $$ $${b_3} = \sup \{ {a_3},{a_4},{a_5},...\} $$
$ \vdots $ 
$${A_n} = \{ {a_n},{a_{n + 1}},{a_{n + 2}},...\} $$ $${b_n} = \sup \{ {a_n},{a_n+1},{a_n+2},...\} $$
As result
        $${A_{n + 1}} \subseteq {A_n}$$ 
And
        ${b_{n + 1}} \leqslant {b_n}$ for $n \in \{ 1,2,3,...\} $ 
        ${b_n} \leqslant {b_1}$
Then sequence $\left( {{b_n}} \right)$ is decreasing.   $ -  -  -  -  - (1)$
We know  $({a_n})_{n = 1}^\infty $ be a bounded , Then there exist $B \geqslant 0$ such that $|{a_n}| \leqslant b$ for $n \in \{ 1,2,3,...\} $
$|{a_n}| \leqslant B$
    $ - B \leqslant {a_n}$
and we know $B \leqslant {a_n} \leqslant {b_n} \leqslant {b_1}$
So we see that sequence $\left( {{b_n}} \right)$ is bounded $ -  -  -  -  - (2)$
From $(1),(2)$ and Monotone convergence Theorem implies $\left( {{b_n}} \right)$ converges

I am  not sure it True or False , Thank for answer

Comment: Yep, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

It looks correct.

(there is a minor typo "and we know $\color{red}{-}B\leqslant a_n\leqslant b_n$")